# how to set jscolor chooser to bs button

Tags: java, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, jscolor

[image]

I want to use `jscolor` chooser as bootstrap button element. I get color code from database. the  input element show the correct color according to color chooser. but bs button show always `ffffff` code.  can anyone explain me the below code's error.

```
<button type="submit" class="jscolor"><%=pc.getName()%></button>
<input type="text" class="jscolor" value=<%=pc.getName()%>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the button class,

```
<button class="jscolor {value: '<%= pc.getName()%>'}"></button>
```

Take a look at the examples shown in the following link.

- [Examples - jscolor Color Picker](http://jscolor.com/examples/)